# Is there harm in using a GFCI outlet as a switch?

Tags: electrical, gfci, safety

I have a GFCI outlet in my garage which is about 4 feet off the ground. I have a couple work lights plugged into it which can only be turned on and off by plugging/unplugging them. I have recently just been using the "Test" and "Reset" buttons on the GFCI outlet to turn the lights on and off. It's a lot easier than unplugging both plugs and later having to bend down to pick them up off the floor and plug them in again.

Can doing this a couple times a day do any damage to the GFCI outlet or to anything plugged in to it?

Comment: I don't have a definitive source, so I'm not posting an answer, but I cannot imagine how one could ever consider using a device in a manner other than for how it was designed and intended would be a good idea.

Comment: @TheEvilGreebo you can’t imagine that at all? Not even a teeny tiny bit?

Comment: They might not be rated to the same magnitude of switching actions. A GFCI might only be rated for 100 actions over its life (3 times a year for 30 years). Where as a wall switch might be rated for 100000 actions over its life (10 times a day for 30 years)

Comment: @Marathon55 for a safety device such as this?  No.  It's meant to intervene and prevent an electric overload - not for routine daily use.  Buy a flipping switch.

Comment: I understand that GFCI outlets are not intended to be used this way, and I understand that *it's possible and may be the case* that the GFCI buttons are not sufficiently durable for frequent use. I understand that if that is indeed the situation, I should not use it like a light switch. But that conclusion is built on a premise which is precisely what my question is asking: Is it in fact the case that GFCI outlets are not durable enough for this kind of use?

Comment: @Marathon55 It is **NOT** a question of **durable**. The problem is that a GFCI test/reset mechanism is much more complex than a simple switch. If it were a plain circuit breaker and appropriately rated (I know I have seen that, but don't recall the classification at the moment that means "can be used as a switch") then it would be different.

Comment: Dan D answered that for you. It's not made to do that. But if you don't mind having to replace your GFCI receptacle earlier than normal, then that's up to you. You appear to be looking for absolution from your sins before you commit them and that doesn't even work in religion, let alone engineering...

Comment: It is cheap and easy to add a switch in the cord of a lamp.

Comment: @TheEvilGreebo becaise lots of people have never rad NEC 110.3, do not appreciate the underlying reasoning, and do not sufficiently fear electricity. Also have seen  too many Code compliant installations unaware their good safety comes from careful design.  It's like the doctor who knows the amazing safety statistics of commercial flight, buys himself a Bonanza and tailspins because he thinks airplane safety is intrinsic.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can a GFCI outlet intentionally and explicitly be used as a switch without violating code?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/116600/can-a-gfci-outlet-intentionally-and-explicitly-be-used-as-a-switch-without-viola)

Comment: @fixer1234 I do not see this question as being a duplicate because I am asking about the durability of the GFCI outlet and that question is asking if there is a code violation.

Comment: OK, valid point.  I'll retract the vote.  It may be worth leaving the comments in place so that others don't do the same thing I did.

Comment: Using a GFCI mechanism as an on/off switch?  [Relevant xkcd](https://xkcd.com/1172/).

Answer (score 4):

### Certain GFCI+receptacle devices are rated for this purpose.

Use one of *those*.

There are GFCI devices whose buttons are *specifically labeled* `Off/Test` and `On/Reset`.  The reason the "off" and "on" are there is because these devices are built and rated to be on/off switches using the GFCI function.  The difference between these and regular GFCIs is these are made for *many, many cycles*.  However, these are difficult to find (especially on the Web, where plain GFCI results bury them) and you will probably need the assistance of an electrical supply house to locate them.  One example is a Leviton 8590-RB, however that's a deadfront and you'd want one with sockets.  Leviton calls it a **switch-rated GFCI**.

[image]
[src](https://www.fruitridgetools.com)

If you're fitting a deadfront GFCI to gain this functionality, just mount a box next to the receptacles and put the GFCI there, using the `LOAD` terminals on the deadfront to feed the receptacle(s).

Far easier to find is the GFCI+receptacle w/ switch device.

[image]
[src](https://www.emisupply.com/)

Typically on these, the switch is two pigtails.  The GFCI+receptacle uses all 4 terminals (LINE hot/neutral LOAD hot/neutral) plus ground, of course.  In this case you *would not* use Test/Reset to turn the load on and off, *you'd use the switch*.  The switch and its load can be placed on the `LOAD` side of the GFCI protection (carefully).

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Comment: @manassehkatz Read [the stack's guidelines](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask), SE is not a "shop for me" site.  So I have been reluctant to be prodded into doing a "product hunt" for you.  As it turns out, it's fairly hard just because of the way Google works, and so the best search heuristic is probably visiting your local electrical supply, which is something I *am unable to* do for you.

Comment: Your updated answer provides plenty of information now - a specific "buy this" isn't needed, just more than the original one-liner. +1

Comment: Installed a GFCI + receptacle a while back.  It's really the best way to go, if you can manage with one outlet.

Answer (score 3):

#### Get an Add-on Switch

I 100% agree with all the others who said "don't do this". The good news is that there is an easy solution. Get a outlet/switch designed to plug into another outlet. Something like [BindMaster 3 Prong Grounded Single Port Power Adapter with Red Indicator On/Off Switch, 1 Pack](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01M7V6U2Q). There are plenty of different brands and styles available, including multiple outlets, WiFi remote control and many other options.

Also note that using a GFCI test button as a switch is very different from using an ordinary circuit breaker as a switch. As I understand it, while using an ordinary circuit breaker as an ordinary on/off switch is often not recommended (and in some situations may even be a code violation), there are at least some circuit breakers which ARE designed to be fully capable of frequent switching use. A GFCI test button is quite different - it actually produces a fault equivalent to a dangerous situation (but within the GCFI module so that it is safe to do so) in order to trigger the GFCI circuit. The **result** if everything works as expected is that the outlet is turned off. But that is a side-effect and NOT the **direct** result of pressing the test button.

As noted in another answer, there are **some** GFCI devices that either include an separate On/Off switch or are *switch-rated*. Those are certainly options as well, though they may be harder to find (i.e., may require going to an electrical supply house rather than Amazon or Home Depot or Lowes).

Answer (score 1):

The TEST and RESET bottons on a GFCI outlet are not designed for use as a light switch or load switch. Constant usage as such will stress it's internal mechanism such that it may not function properly when called upon actually in it's ground fault trip mode.

If you want to see for yourself then take apart a GFCI outlet and a light switch and see how much more complex and how many more moving parts there are in the GFCI.